# Install release app on iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cordova

I created an app in Xcode 4.x and it's now ready for release.
So i created a distribution profile for it and added that to xcode.

I also selected that profile in both the `Project` and `Target` build settings.

I also added an Entitlements.plist to the root of my project with just one setting:

```
"get-task-allow" -> "NO"
```

After that i cleaned the project. When the cleaning was done i clicked on `Product -> Archive` to build an .IPA file.

I tried to install the IPA file on my iphone through iTunes but i got the error:

> 'App name' failed to install

So basically my question now is. is it even possible to install a release version like this? Or is there another problem...??

PS.
The entire project is created with PhoneGap/Xcode. Don't know if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to add your iPhone to the Ad Hoc distribution profile you're using? If so, check that the bundle specifier matches between your application and profile.

Comment: No i don't have an Ad Hoc distribution profile. I made an "App Store" profile. I wanted to test if everything worked fine, so i tried to install that app onto my device. But when it tried to install it gave me the error "failed to install". Is it save to assume that this is because i made an "App Store" profile, which only works when you get it from the app store...??

Comment: Exactly. You want to distribute ad hoc, so you need an ad-hoc distribution provision

Comment: Applications signed with the App Store profile will not install on your device, you need the Ad Hoc certificate for this. App Store profile is only for App Store submission. Remember to add your device's UUID to your ad hoc profile before downloading the profile from developer.apple.com.